# If-Else ladder in Excel To sort data

Tags: excel, if-statement

I was doing R&D on Excel. And wanted to use If-else ladder in column of excel.
Let's say I have a 2 columns and I calculated the difference between the two columns. Now, If the difference is between a range of (-5 to +5), if should display something or if Difference greater than 5, it should display something and for rest i.e. difference < -5, should display something else.
I tried and came up with this

```
=IF("H2>5",<something1>, IF("H2<5",<something2>))
```

How to put the range part in this if-else ladder? Also the above If else is not giving value but the result is turning out to be #VALUE.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `=IF(H2>5,"Something1",IF(H2<-5,"something2","something3"))`, but I will suggest that you do either ascending or descending in your `IF` function if you have more to check.

Comment: @ian0411 it needs to be `H2<-5`, simply less than 5 won't make the range.

Comment: @tigeravatar, thank you for catching that.  Good eyes.

Comment: @ian0411: Thanks for helping out fellas! Cheers!!

Comment: @tigeravatar coz I wasn't able to add ur name in previous comment, cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=IF(H2<-5,"Negative",IF(H2<=5,"In Range","Positive"))
```

[image]

Comment: nice job, editted the question, and answered first!  Even beat Scott...he must not have had his coffee yet or is on his smart phone commuting to work.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Probably Scott was not interested in answering simple question.

Comment: @Mrig: I still have less than 15 reputation, but they recorded my vote :P

Answer (score 0):

There could be 3 possibilities only, 1 the answer is between -5 to 5 inculdining -5 and 5. 2 greater then 5. 3 smaller than -5. so this should work

```
=IF(AND(H2>=-5,H2<=5),"between -5 &5",IF(H2<-5,"Smaller than-5",IF(H2>5,"greater than 5 ")))
```

let me know if this is what is required.